# Marcar y desmarcar independientemente checkbox

Tags: html5, materialize, checkbox

Tengo dos checks, que funcionan mal, marca y desmarca desde el segundo check al primero, quiero que funcionen independientemente.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox" class="filled-in" /><label  for="myCheckbox"></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox" class="filled-in" /><label  for="myCheckbox"></label>
```

Answer (score 3):

Es que tienen el mismo `id` y no debe ser así.

- Cada identificador es único.
- La etiqueta `label` *debería* estar relacionada con un único elemento o identificador.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox" class="filled-in" /><label  for="myCheckbox"></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox2" class="filled-in" /><label  for="myCheckbox2"></label>
```